# How to add a new column in sql server based on Select query

Tags: sql-server

I have just created a simple query the concatenate 2 columns and create a column with this concatenation.

Now I want to `ADD` a new column to the table base on the below query

```
SELECT Convert(NVARCHAR(50), [cell_name]) + '_' + Convert(NVARCHAR(50), 
     [n_cell_name]) AS st_gsm_df_relation_key
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[gsm_df_relation]
```

I want `ALTER TABLE` or something based on this query.

Comment: So what is your question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `alter` :

```
alter table table_name
   add st_gsm_df_relation_key_ as Convert(nvarchar(50),[cell_name])+'_'+Convert(nvarchar(50),[n_cell_name]);
```

You can also use `concat()` :

```
alter table table_name
   add st_gsm_df_relation_key_ as concat(Convert(nvarchar(50),[cell_name]), '_', Convert(nvarchar(50),[n_cell_name]));
```

`concat()` will ignore `null`s when either `cell_name` or `n_cell_name` have `null`.

Comment: thanks alot that's actually what I need :)  it was solved

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Haroon, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.